# How do I find a potential pattern between x1, x2, and y?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file, I read it by Panda. And I need to find out any patterns in the data and provide the evidence and Python script for the pattern.

Here is some data:

```
          x1        x2         y
0  -0.473137 -1.633617 -0.860691
1  -1.069586 -0.034465  0.002398
2   1.839980 -0.146891 -0.417169
3   0.656758 -1.329676 -2.202951
4   0.020591 -1.286592 -1.313084
..       ...       ...       ...
95  0.507456 -0.121615 -0.183330
96  0.368856 -1.067686 -1.461507
97 -0.519602  0.391609  0.579737
98  0.818727  0.096359  0.271610
99 -0.272681  0.080744  0.139471
```

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("./hw0_p1.csv")
print(data)
```

Comment: try some kind of regression.

Comment: you could try a simple perceptron

Comment: This question is unclear. What sort of "pattern" do you envision trying to find? A pattern in the numbers down the columns? Relationship between x and y? Whether there's a signal-processing relationship? Can you provide a [mcve] with a sample input and a sample output, as well as _code for what you've tried so far_?

Answer (score 2):

This is completely unanswerable, because "some pattern" is mathematically meaningless. There are a wide variety of things you can look into depending on what kinds of patterns you think might be present in the data, and how hard you're willing to look (and how much data you have to work with), so you really need a thorough "Data Science", "Data Analysis", or perhaps "Machine Learning" background to approach this. Consider looking into `scikit-learn` for ideas and code support, and google around for ideas like Pearson Correlation, cross-correlation, co-variance, and general regression techniques (scikit-learn implements a whole pile of 'em).

Answer (score 0):

Well this a multivariate regression problem.

1. You can either look for trends using a scatter matrix.
2. Using correlation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

corr = data.corr()
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm')
```

3. Run some RandomForest using Sklearn and see if it predicts well.
4. Use this [How to perform three variable correlation with Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369159/how-to-perform-three-variable-correlation-with-python-pandas) to learn the correlation between x1 and x2 against y.